# Pig error: unexpected character '\'

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to hadoop and pig. I am trying to run a sample pig script in a CentOS6 enviroment on VMWARE:

```
records = LOAD '2013_subset.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS              
(Year,Month,DayofMonth,DayOfWeek,DepTime,CRSDepTime,ArrTime,\               
CRSArrTime,UniqueCarrier,FlightNum,TailNum,ActualElapsedTime,\              
CRSElapsedTime,AirTime,ArrDelay,DepDelay,Origin,Dest,\              
Distance:int,TaxiIn,TaxiOut,Cancelled,CancellationCode,\              
Diverted,CarrierDelay,WeatherDelay,NASDelay,SecurityDelay,\              LateAircraftDelay);milage_recs = 
GROUP records ALL;tot_miles = FOREACH milage_recs GENERATE SUM(records.Distance);STORE tot_miles INTO /user/root/totalmiles;
```

This code is save to a file called totalmiles.pig. After it runs, it completes with the following error:

> ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GRUNT - -ERROR:  Unexpected character '\'

When remove the characters '\' from the code, I get a different error:

> ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GRUNT - -ERROR:  mismatched input '/' expecting QUOTEDSTRING

I have not been able to find a solution to this particular error.I have run this on a different VM (virtulabox) under Centos7 and received a different error a *parameter subsitution :i* . I was hoping that someone might be able to shed some light on this.

Thanks!
wasmithpfs

Comment: @iMassakre As your comment does not help in answering the question I have flagged it as non constructive. Please don't spam in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the backslashes i.e. "\" and in the store statement the path must be enclosed in quotes.

```
records = LOAD '2013_subset.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (Year,Month,DayofMonth,DayOfWeek,DepTime,CRSDepTime,ArrTime,RSArrTime,UniqueCarrier,FlightNum,TailNum,ActualElapsedTime,CRSElapsedTime,AirTime,ArrDelay,DepDelay,Origin,Dest,Distance:int,TaxiIn,TaxiOut,Cancelled,CancellationCode,Diverted,CarrierDelay,WeatherDelay,NASDelay,SecurityDelay,LateAircraftDelay);
milage_recs = GROUP records ALL;
tot_miles = FOREACH milage_recs GENERATE SUM(records.Distance);
STORE tot_miles INTO '/user/root/totalmiles';
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be quite clear:

The characters `\` should not be there.

After solving that, the code can compile a bit further and you run into the next error:

Where you have a `/` a quoted string is expected.

Try to indicate the path with quotes, like:

```
'/user/root/totalmiles'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:
1. In load statement, you don't need '\'. Query parser can handle newline. Try below load statement.

```
records = LOAD '2013_subset.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (Year, Month, DayofMonth,
DyOfWeek, DepTime, CRSDepTime, ArrTime, CRSArrTime, UniqueCarrier, FlightNum, TailNum,
ActualElapsedTime, CRSElapsedTime, AirTime, ArrDelay, DepDelay, Origin, Dest, Distance:int,
TaxiIn, TaxiOut, Cancelled, CancellationCode, Diverted, CarrierDelay, WeatherDelay, 
NASDelay, SecurityDelay, LateAircraftDelay);
```

2. In store statement you should have single quotes after INTO statements around output path. Try below:

   STORE tot_miles INTO '/user/root/totalmiles';

Comment: I have used your advice and have been able to run the program a bit further. But now I get a pigcontext error: "2016-06-13 20:24:53,021 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext - Undefined parameter : BOXE"  "2016-06-13 20:24:53,640 [main]  - ERROR 2997 Encountered IOException.org.apache.pig.toold.parameters.ParameterSubstitutionException:Undefined parameter : BOXE"  . What do these errors mean? Where is "BOXE" coming from, as it is not in the data file nor is it in the pig script. Please advise.

Comment: That looks like parameter substitution error. Which doesn't occur unless you are trying to use "BOXE" parameter somewhere is script and you have not defined that parameter using -param feature of pig. If that is not the case, I need to see full stack of error to understand what's wrong. Also I need to know how you ran the script. I am assuming you are using same set of commands as in original post.